# Running a PHP site in an unoccupied port

Tags: php, cmd, localhost

I have a different app runnning in `localhost:8000`. If I run a second app through the server, it dumps the one running and it places itself in this port. I need to be able to run both. Ideally in separate ports:

App1 in localhost:8000 Which runs a React/webpack/node app

App2 in localhost:8080 Which runs the PHP version of the site.

I'm using atom as my IDE with a built-in command terminal if that helps. And Apache as my local server (XAMPP and WAMPP in mac and Win respectively)

Comment: What do you mean by "dumps the one running"?

Comment: It replaces with the one I'm telling it to run. I want it to run in a separate port without interrupting the other one

Comment: Then just add another Virtual Host config on the Apache for port 8080 and direct all requests to it to the second app?

Comment: But how? Asking politely? Lol. I don't know how to do this. Any link with instructions. This is the first time I've ever had the need for this

Comment: Hope [this](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html) or [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts) helps

Comment: I'll look into it as soon as I get back home. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to do it without having to do much work creating VirtualHosts and using PHP Built-in Server

Step 1 - Open your XAMPP console and click on the Shell
[image]

Step 2 - CD to $PATH. For example cd c:\xampp\htdocs\site_folder
Step 3 - `Type php -S localhost:8080` and hit Enter
[image]

Step 4 - In the browser, navigate to localhost:8080 and it will show.

Step 5 - For the second website, open a separate CMD terminal and repeat the process by selecting the $PATH to that website folder and assigning a different port numbe (i.e 8000), hit Enter, navigate to that localhost:8000 in a separate browser tab or window and voila! Now both sites are running independently!